# Gateway API - Apache APISIX with Secured Websockets

Tags: websocket, api-gateway

I am trying to add an API Gateway to a client-server system, which communicates through WebSockets.

The Server is an audio recognition engine that sits in a remote machine, and clients are connecting to it through WebSockets ('wss://...'), sending audio files and receiving their text translate representation.
My main goal is to add a free open-source API Gateway in the middle in order to authenticate\authorize\rate limit\etc (Tried Kong\Tyk\krakenD, but they are not free).
After searching the web, I focused on Apache APISIX gateway.
As a test, I managed to connect the APISIX to a client-server which communicates by http/https and it worked fine.
Moreover, I managed to connect the client with the server on regular websocket connection (ws://) and the data transactions were successful, but no matter what I do I cant connect to the secured connection. Are there any special configurations I should edit in the dashboard?

I'm wondering if anyone knows from experience if it's possible to use
the  secured WebSockets with Apache APISIX and if yes, how exactly it should be done - because the docs are missing any informative info\examples, or if there are better solutions known to my problem.

The only WebSocket reference in APISIX dashboard - [image: image of APISIX dashboard only WebSocket button]

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is create an SSL object (you can find it in the sidebar on the left side). See https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/admin-api/#ssl to learn the APISIX SSL object.

You can see an example at https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/certificate

The SSL object provides the required TLS Certificate and Private Key so that this key pair can be used in a TLS handshake according to the TLS SNI sent from clients. After that, your client established a secured connection with APISIX, and now you can send the WebSocket traffic securely.

Comment: Test cases are also covered in the Apache APISIX project  https://github.com/apache/apisix/blob/c9ce0362fc5201295c73398db2d50d32c9197462/t/node/upstream-websocket.t#L226-L276